# Use linq to combine 2 classes into a 3rd collection

Tags: vb.net, linq

If I have 2 classes and want to take 2 properties from each class, and combine them into a separate collection, how would this be done using linq?

Say the 2 classes are:

```
class guitars
    public ID
    public title
    public manufacturer
end class

class drums
    public ID
    public title
    public manufacturer
end class
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
   Private Interface Instruments
       Property ID As String
       Property name As String
   End Interface

   Dim results = From item In guitars _
        Select New Instruments() With _
                         { _
                             .ID = item.ID, _
                             .name = item.Title _
                         }

   Dim results2 = From item In drums _
        Select New Instruments() With _
                          { _
                              .ID = item.ID, _
                              .name = item.Title _
                          }

Dim combined = results + results2
```

Comment: Those class names should not be plural.

Comment: ... and you shoould make it `OPTION STRICT` with explicit types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it much simpler than that.

Just make both classes implement the `IInstrument` interface.
You can then write

```
guitars.Cast(Of IInstrument)().Concat(drums)
```

Comment: Isn't `Concat(drums.Cast(of Instrument))` necessary?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Only on .Net 3.5.  On 4.0+, `IEnumerable(Of T)` is covariant.  In fact, I think that calling `Concat(Of IInstrument)()` would work with no `Cast()`s at all.

Answer (score 1):

Union or Concat depending on wether or not you want to allow duplicates in the list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763068.aspx

```
Dim Combined = results.Union(results2) ' no duplicates allowed
Dim Combined = results.Concat(results2) 'duplicates allowed
```

EDIT: Added Concat at the behest of MatthewWhited. He is totally right. The list is distinct according to the MSDN.

Comment: Just a note `Union` will create a distinct list. `Concat` will just add the second list to the end of the first.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Note that it won't actually be distinct unless there is a `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: True, I was just trying to point out there is a difference.  If someone was to try the same thing with a set of integers or strings they may go nuts trying to figure out why it worked one way but not the other.